# Validation passes of unchecked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate radio buttons but the valuation does not work, the next page gets loaded even if no radio button is checked. I have tried different approaches but none of them work, at one point I had pop-up window appearing, as for other messages, but next page was loaded anyway.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<fieldset id="Radio">
Smoking <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking1" value="Smoking">
Non-smoking <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking2" value="Non-smoking">
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
var radio1 = document.getElementById("smoking1");
var radio2 = document.getElementById("smoking2");

if ((!radio1.checked) && (!radio2.checked)){
        window.alert("You must check one of the options in Smoking Preferences field!");
        reservation.radio1.focus();
        return false;

    }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: And do you call that code when the form is submitted?? It does not just keep magically running if it is not called via some event.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the code, rest of my validation works fine apart from radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reservation.radio1.focus();
```

There is no element with the name radio1 in your code sample.

add `name="radio1"` to both your radio buttons.

Now the focus will not work since name will return *two* so you need to select the first one.

```
reservation.radio1[0].focus();
```